# Cannot name database in RDS management console

Tags: rds

I'm creating an RDS postgreSQL 10.6 instance and when I name it the name does not save.

I can add a database name when creating the instance:

[image]

But after it's created the name doesn't seem to be saved :

[image]

Note `DB name` is blank.  RDS bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't find the reason why my custom name does not apply, the default database name is `postgres` so now I can connect with my client