# RDS set Database name AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I am new to the world of cloud and have much to learn so forgive me if this is a simple and obvious question to ask. I am trying to deploy a WordPress website on the cloud. I am following this tutorial as a starting point [WordPress Website with an External Amazon RDS Database to Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hawordpress-tutorial.html#php-hawordpress-tutorial-install)

I created my database but the name I give it does not show up
[image]

I have seen the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56077138/cannot-name-database-in-rds-management-console) , it mentions that it sets the db to a default name and nothing more.

> I would like to know if there is a way to rename/give the database a
>   name after creating it and if the issue is a bug.

Thank you in advance for your help and guidance.

Comment: Can you explain where it does not show up and how did you create the db

Comment: @ArunK it's not showing up under the configuration of the database. I created the database by clicking on the create database button in the RDS console, I enter in my choices like size and type and a give it a name but the name is blank when looking at the configuration section of the instance

Comment: I think you have created a RDS db instance and then you have also given a name for a default database?  which step are you doing now in the tutorial

Comment: Try access the database through any mysql client. see if you can locate the db, otherwise you can always create another database

Comment: @ArunK I created a new one and now it fine, thank you

Comment: Awesome.great work